# Flip bool: performance comparison of x=!x versus x^=1

Tags: c++, c, optimization, assembly

I am aware of two techniques for flipping a bool:

```
x = !x
```

and

```
x ^= 1
```

I prefer the second, in the same way that I prefer x++ over x+=1 over x=x+1.

But are they guaranteed to produce the same Assembly code?

And if not, is there some rationale to favour one over the other?

Comment: You can easily check the assembly code and answer yourself.

Comment: Does `x ^= 1` really do the same thing? what happens if `bool x = (bool)2`?

Comment: @ikh Conversion to `__Bool` in `bool x = (bool) 2;` has the effect of setting `x` to `1`, in C99.

Comment: @Maroun, the assembly code may differ between architectures. I suspect x^=1 forces promotion to integer so on an 8-bit microprocessor x^=1 maybe much more costly...

Comment: @Pi If “the assembly code may differ between architectures”, then why do you ask people on the internet who do not have the same compiler and architecture as you?

Comment: @Pi an 8-bit compiler that doesn't eliminate the virtual cost of promoted intermediate values, when the final result is assigned back to an 8-bit variable, would be useless.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, a question about a general beahviour can never be answered by "try it yourself". This would only reasolve a specific case with a particular implementation, but doesn't provide an answer for the generic case.

Comment: @Pascal, someone who has experience of assembly programming on different architectures may have an insight I do not.

Comment: @PascalCuoq that is just test code.. all "not zero" value is true. Is there any guarantee that `bool` should be `0` or `1`?

Comment: @Pi, the only crroect asnwer which can be given is the one that Potatswatter already provided. There is no guruantee for a particular translation, because this is implementation specific.

Answer (score 4):

There are never any guarantees about same assembly code. Yes, given `bool x`, they both do exactly the same thing. Yes, that implies they are likely to be the same.

It is a common fallacy that writing expressions in an unusual way might make them faster. Avoid working with anyone who makes habits based on such ideas.

`x = ! x` is clearer because `!` is defined in terms of Boolean values.

Comment: *`!` is defined specifically for Boolean values* may be misleading, as the operator can be applied to far more types than booleans only.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Other values are converted to `bool` first, so I'll stick with this.

Comment: I beg to differ. Surely a custom `operator !()` does not have `this` converted to a boolean before it runs.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Overloading is not the topic of this question.

Comment: In C, `!` is “defined specifically” for all scalar types (and it returns an `int`).

Comment: There is no good way to answer questions tagged both C and C++. I was only complementing your answer but my comment was not a suggestion to edit it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq `!` is the operator for Boolean negation. I'm referring to clarity for human readers, not program semantics.

Comment: "It is a common fallacy that writing expressions in an unusual way might make them faster": I disagree with that. In particular, contrived branch-free expressions can be very useful in inner loops.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ever heard of `cmov`?

Answer (score 3):

> I prefer the second, in the same way that I prefer x++ over x+=1 over x=x+1.

Please prefer the first. It is expected and easily understood by most programmers. The second form, only works for values 0 and 1 in integer's case.

> But are they guaranteed to produce the same Assembly code?

No.

> And if not, is there some rationale to favour one over the other?

Decreasing the ratio of "wtf/loc" of you code (i.e. *how many times would another developer look at your code and say "WTF?!?", over every n lines of code*).

**Edit:** Either way, you will probably never see a real-world example of an application made faster by replacing one expression with the other. It is a matter of style, not a matter of performance.

Answer (score 2):

The second expression is simply a source of difficulty found bugs. For example you may think that some expression has type bool while its actual type due to the integer promotion or usual arithmetic conversion is some integral type.

Consider the following code snippet

```
unsigned int x = 3;

x ^= 1;

std::cout << x << std::endl;

if ( x == false ) std::cout << "All is O'k\n";
else std::cout << "Oops. Something is wrong!\n"; 

x = 3;

x = !x;

std::cout << x << std::endl;

if ( x == false ) std::cout << "All is O'k\n";
else std::cout << "Oops. Something is wrong!\n";
```

So using expression `x ^= 1;` to flip a boolean value can only confuse readers of the code.

So I would prefer to use `x = !x;` instead of `x ^= 1;`

Do not forget about the principle **KISS**: Keep It Simple Stupid.:)

Though for example in C the result of `operator !` has type int nevertheless the value of the operation is either 0 or 1.

From the C Standard

> 5 The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of
>   its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand
>   compares equal to 0.

So for both languages there is a guarantee that the result will be exactly either 0 or 1 for **any source value.**

Answer (score 1):

`!x` and `x^1` are clearly different operations.

The former is a *logical* negation, returning a 0/1 value. It makes sense to use it on bools.

The latter is a *bitwise* exclusive or, returning any possible value. It shouldn't be used on a bool. (For xoring bools, prefer the inequality comparison `!=`). It is also less efficient in unoptimized code as it invoves and extra operand (1).

K&R forgot to provide a `!!` operator, that you would have loved, and possibly `~~`.

Comment: And also `**` and `//` operators (multiply and divide by 2), that I would have loved ;-)